# Electron: How to set a custom directory for user data (--user-data-dir)

Tags: electron, chromium

I want to set the --user-data-dir of my electron app to a custom directory, in my case, I would like it to default to a folder in the public directory so any users running the app will share the same asset directory.

It doesn't seem like Electron's [appendSwitch()](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md) function supports this (and didn't work when I tried), so i'm kind of lost on how to implement this switch.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In an application built with Electron, you usually get the default user data directory dynamically by using [app.getPath(name)](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname) from the main process:

```
const { app } = require ('electron');
const userDataPath = app.getPath ('userData');
```

It is also possible to set the path to a custom directory by using [app.setPath(name, path)](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetpathname-path):

```
app.setPath ('userData', "path/to/new/directory");
```

> Overrides the path to a special directory or file associated with
>   name. If the path specifies a directory that does not exist, the
>   directory will be created by this method. On failure an Error is
>   thrown.
>
> You can only override paths of a name defined in app.getPath.
>
> By default, web pages' cookies and caches will be stored under the
>   userData directory. If you want to change this location, you have to
>   override the userData path before the ready event of the app module is
>   emitted.

Comment: Solved my issue! I kept thinking I needed to send in a flag or switch and didn't realize it was this simple. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: It says you should override `userData` path before the ready event of the app module is emitted. Where would that be? Is there an even emitted before `ready`?

Comment: @dguay Anywhere at the top of your index.js or main electron process file where you set all your global variables. As long as you've defined all your variables before listening for and/or calling the `ready` listener, you're fine.