# Separate cookies of multiple windows

Tags: electron

I'd like to write an [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) app, which is based on a number of windows.

Using this app, I'd like to be able to log in into a web-app using different roles in different windows.

Therefore, I need a feature to store cookies in different windows of the app at different locations. **HTML, JS code and cookies** data of window A should **not see** that of windows B.

Alternatively, I could image to somehow **trap set-cookie requests** and keep them in memory, thus **not using app global cookie storage on HD**.

> Could someone provide code for this feature?

I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587035/electron-how-to-set-a-custom-directory-for-user-data-user-data-dir), which explains how to [app.setPath()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetpathname-path) of `userData`. Unfortunately `userData` is app-global, not e.g. window local.

If I would be now able to trap each `cookie-set` operation of each [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window), I would be able to use `app.setPath()` and switch the cookie storage based on the window, the trap was fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution:

First create a partition. Let name it `SomeNameForMySession` :

```
const partition = 'persist:SomeNameForMySession'
```

Then pass the [partition](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) to a [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) like so at creation time:

```
var ctrlWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        partition: partition
    }
})
```

If another [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) gets another [partition](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) with another name, the windows have fully separated cookies.
If another [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) gets the same [partition](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions), the windows share cookie storage.

Using this, you may for example trace, what cookie events happen in **session of the named partition**:

```
// First find the correct session based on the partitions name
const ses2 = session.fromPartition( partition2 )

// Then, add a listener
ses2.cookies.addListener( 'changed', function ( event, cookie, cause, removed ) {
    console.log('COOKIE: ' + cookie.name + ' :: ' + cookie.value )
})
```