# VSCode - what exactly --user-data-dir is specifiying

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, parameters

What exactly is `--user-data-dir` specifiying?

From `--help` parameter:

`--user-data-dir <dir>             Specifies the directory that user data is kept in. Can be used to open multiple distinct instances of Code.`

Is it storing some temporary files there?

Is it about the access path to config files?

I am asking as I want to run VSCode (or Codium to be more exact) with `sudo` (I want to edit system config file that is read restricted) which requires this parameter for reasons unclear to me.

Comment: I think for "mortal" user, it would default to: `~/.vscode`, as "root" you'd have to specify it accordingly ... [see also](https://askubuntu.com/q/803343/707903)

Comment: VSC saves some stuff for each Workspace/Folder it has opened, it also needs a place to store the extensions you have installed (maybe a different directory argument)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sub>Since `sudo`-ing VS Code *at command-line launch* is **only a thing on Linux,** this question assumes you're on Linux, and restricts its context to Linux.</sub>

### TL;DR

**To answer your question directly:** the `user-data-dir` parameter points to a folder where **all personalisation except extensions** resides — unique to each user.

#### Why does `sudo`-ing Code need `--user-data-dir`?

In typical installations of either OS and VS Code, *this folder owned by the regular user **cannot be accessed by the superuser.***

Hence a VS Code session running with effective UID=0 tries but fails to write to the invoking user's (*not the superuser's*) config folder. This is what the error message prevents from happening, by forcing the user to provide an explicit `root`-accessible folder.

---

### Detailed Explanation

There are two main folders that VS Code uses to store configuration data:

1. An **extensions** folder (self explanatory) — contained in `~/.vscode`<sup>*</sup>
2. **`user-data-dir`**; a folder for ***all other personalisable things*** (settings, keybindings, GitHub/MS account credential caches, themes, `tasks.json`, *you name it*)<sup>*</sup>

On Linux the latter is located in **`~/.config/Code`**, and has file permissions mode `0700` (unreadable and unwritable by anybody other than the owner).<sup>[[1]](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3068#issuecomment-206099168)</sup>

This causes issues, as VS Code tries and fails to access said directory. The logical solution is to either modify the permissions (recursively) of `~/.config/Code` to allow `root` access, or — arguably saner and objectively more privacy-respecting — to use a *separate directory altogether* for the `sudo`'ed VS Code to access.

The latter strategy is what the community decided to adopt at large; [this commit from 2016](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/6456f85788a8c526d73957656aaf2a5a04091aa7#diff-7c0b8a8faa63c7cafe91db16c21fb07444a703b014ee6be11e79631e832702ee) started making it compulsory to pass an explicit `--user-data-dir` when `sudo`-ing VS Code on Linux.

---

##### Should You be Doing This in the First Place?

**Probably not!** If your goal is to modify system config files, then you could stick to an un-elevated instance of Code, which would prompt you to <kbd>Save as Admin...</kbd> when you try to save. See [this answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/820205/1265734) on why you probably want to avoid elevating VS Code without reason (***unless you understand the risks and/or have to***), and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027243/1265734) on the same thread on what you could do instead.
However, if the concerned file is **read-restricted to `root` as well,** as in the O.P’s case, then you hardly have a choice ; `sudo` away!

<sub>*If you want to know more about the above **two folder paths** on different OSes, see [[2]](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_where-are-extensions-installed) and [[3]](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations)</sub>

<sup>Hope this was helpful!</sup>

Comment: "Save as Admin" is not solving problem of failing to open such file.

Though "The absolute best thing to do to is make a copy of a restricted file, edit it, and copy it back when you're absolutely sure it's finished." is probably a superior solution.

Comment: Ahhh, so the system config file concerned here is also read-restricted?  
Now I see why you're going through all this xD :/

Comment: Changed my answer as well to reflect the possibility of read-restricted-to-root files :)

Comment: FYI, on macOS the default `user-data-dir` is **`$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code`**

Comment: That’s true!
A valuable addition to those reading this thread, perhaps. Thanks @ryenus!
Didn’t include that info in this answer though, since running the `code` tool using `sudo` on macOS doesn’t seem to launch it as root at all, as of this comment 

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of stuff goes in the user data directory.

VS Code is built on Electron (which is built on Chromium). Electron and Chromium runtime things are part of what goes in there. That includes various caches and configuration. [Chromium itself also has/uses a user data directory](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/user_data_dir.md), Electron [builds on that](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname) (see also [Electron: How to set a custom directory for user data (--user-data-dir)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48587035/11107541)), and VS Code does as well.

Ignoring the Electron and Chromium bits and focusing on the VS Code-specific bits, there's a bunch of caches, configuration, and preference storage.

- `User/` contains

  - settings.json
  - tasks.json ([yes, you can have a global tasks.json](/a/77357423/11107541))
  - keybindings.json
  - `snippets/` - a directory containing your user snippets files (all these for the default profile)
  - a directory containing files like listed above for non-default profiles
  - directories where storage goes for [the global and workspace storage mechanisms in VS Code's API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#data-storage), as well as a bunch of VS Code preferences storage (like whether or not to show you a particular notification again), and workbench layout info.
  - `History/` subdirectory for [Local Storage](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_local-history) (versions/copies of files that you saved through VS Code).
- `Backups`/ is for [Hot Exit](/q/56076678/11107541) (files that were unsaved when closing a workspace)

There's other stuff I'm probably missing, but those are the things that I find notable.

As for stuff that *doesn't* go under the user data directory, that would include the extensions installation directory, which is typically `~/.vscode/extensions`, and [`argv.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77249826/11107541), which is typically under `~/.vscode`. Different VS Code product variants will have different, but similarly placed directories for this, such as `~/.vscode-insiders`, `~/.vscode-server`, etc.

When VS Code has been launched, you can find the data directory the current instance is using by running `Developer: Open User Data Folder` command in the command palette. The default user data directory is platform-dependent, but always two directories up from the default profile's default settings.json file location [as specified in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations):

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Code\`
- macOS: `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/`
- Linux: `$HOME/.config/Code/`

Putting the user data directory under the VS Code installation directory is part of [how you create a "Portable VS Code" installation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable).

Sometimes when you report a VS Code bug ticket, the maintainers will ask that you try to reproduce the issue with a new user data directory.

Answer (score -1):

It might be helpful to easily find the default location of the user-data-dir on any OS.  It can be found with this command:

```
Developer: Open User Data Folder
workbench.action.openUserDataFolder
```

which is in the Insiders Build v1.75 now, Stable soon.  Opens your OS file explorer app to the location.