# Where does VS Code store the data for its Local History feature?

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory, path, local, history

VS Code just introduced a new local history feature built into the application. However I cannot find where the older version of files I worked on are stored on my computer when local history is turned on.

Does anyone know where the local history of older file versions are stored on Windows and Linux computers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see local history changes in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446901/how-to-see-local-history-changes-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: This is a duplicate

Comment: although the question has already been answered, I strongly suggest using the optimized search tool in the windows file system called "everything search". Much faster and more customizable than the standard search.

Comment: @JΛYDΞV I originally thought so too, but upon a closer look, actually, I disagree. that question can include answers about viewing the history _in_ VS Code itself, where this is more of a backend question about the implementation details.

Answer (score 5):

From https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26339#issuecomment-1070884696

> That depends on how VSCode is run:
>
> - local desktop client with local workspace: local file system
> - local desktop client with remote file system backed workspace: remote file system
> - web client with remote file system backed workspace: remote file system
> - web client with non-file-system-backed workspace (e.g. vscode.dev): IndexedDB in the browser
>
> When stored in the file system, there is a folder called `History` in
> the folder `User` that is stored at the `user-data-dir`, which depends
> on the OS you are on. That is the same location where e.g. also
> backups go or UI state.

Following those directions, on Windows 11 local file system I found it at

`C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\History`

for Stable and

`C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\Code - Insiders\User\History`

for Insiders.

I can't answer it for Linux.  But see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70453798/836330 for more on `user-data-dir` and Linux.  It says it is in `~/.config/Code` on Linux but I can't personally verify that.

Comment: when connecting to a remote Linux machine, it's under `~/.vscode-server/data/User/History` on the remote machine

Answer (score 0):

in VSCode appSettingsHome/History

Windows：C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\History
MacOS：$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/History.
Linux：$HOME/.config/Code/User/History

source code:

```html
    @memoize
    get localHistoryHome(): URI { return joinPath(this.appSettingsHome, 'History'); }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Linux**
/home/USER/.config/VSCodium/User/History/

**Windows**
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\VSCodium\User\History

I am using VSCodium, so I imagine you will replace VSCodium with Visual Studio Code in the path.