# How to undo after running sudo code . --user-data-dir='.'?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line

I was doing the VSCode configuration, but accidentally I saw this command line which I am not sure what it is doing.

However, after running, it always creates the cache data whenever I start my VSCode.

Note: Whenever I typed this command in any directory, it'll automatically shown those folder and file in that directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By setting `--user-data-dir` you're telling VS Code where it should keep your user / session data, which is why it's creating all of those new directories. This is necessary because when you run `code` as sudo, it doesn't know where your user data directory is, since you're running as a different user. Like this answer says, you probably shouldn't be running `code` with sudo: [VSCode - what exactly --user-data-dir is specifiying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70396384/vscode-what-exactly-user-data-dir-is-specifiying). See that answer for suggestions on alternatives.

As for deleting the data it made, just a simple `sudo rm -rf <dir>` should do the trick (be careful of course).