# What arguments are supported in VS Code's argv.json file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

argv.json - What arguments are supported by the file?

```
// This configuration file allows you to pass permanent command line arguments to VS Code.
// Only a subset of arguments is currently supported to reduce the likelihood of breaking
// the installation.
//
// PLEASE DO NOT CHANGE WITHOUT UNDERSTANDING THE IMPACT
//
// NOTE: Changing this file requires a restart of VS Code.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the argv.json file in VS Code (you can use the `Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)), you can actually hover over fields to see their description, and trigger suggestions to see what other properties are supported. The schema for desktop installations is defined in [src/vs/workbench/electron-sandbox/desktop.contribution.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/electron-sandbox/desktop.contribution.ts). Quoting from that file in version 1.83:

> ```js
> const schema: IJSONSchema = {
>   id: argvDefinitionFileSchemaId,
>   allowComments: true,
>   allowTrailingCommas: true,
>   description: 'VSCode static command line definition file',
>   type: 'object',
>   additionalProperties: false,
>   properties: {
>     locale: {
>       type: 'string',
>       description: localize('argv.locale', 'The display Language to use. Picking a different language requires the associated language pack to be installed.')
>     },
>     'disable-hardware-acceleration': {
>       type: 'boolean',
>       description: localize('argv.disableHardwareAcceleration', 'Disables hardware acceleration. ONLY change this option if you encounter graphic issues.')
>     },
>     'force-color-profile': {
>       type: 'string',
>       markdownDescription: localize('argv.forceColorProfile', 'Allows to override the color profile to use. If you experience colors appear badly, try to set this to `srgb` and restart.')
>     },
>     'enable-crash-reporter': {
>       type: 'boolean',
>       markdownDescription: localize('argv.enableCrashReporter', 'Allows to disable crash reporting, should restart the app if the value is changed.')
>     },
>     'crash-reporter-id': {
>       type: 'string',
>       markdownDescription: localize('argv.crashReporterId', 'Unique id used for correlating crash reports sent from this app instance.')
>     },
>     'enable-proposed-api': {
>       type: 'array',
>       description: localize('argv.enebleProposedApi', "Enable proposed APIs for a list of extension ids (such as \`vscode.git\`). Proposed APIs are unstable and subject to breaking without warning at any time. This should only be set for extension development and testing purposes."),
>       items: {
>         type: 'string'
>       }
>     },
>     'log-level': {
>       type: ['string', 'array'],
>       description: localize('argv.logLevel', "Log level to use. Default is 'info'. Allowed values are 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug', 'trace', 'off'.")
>     },
>     'disable-chromium-sandbox': {
>       type: 'boolean',
>       description: localize('argv.disableChromiumSandbox', "Disables the Chromium sandbox. This is useful when running VS Code as elevated on Linux and running under Applocker on Windows.")
>     },
>     'use-inmemory-secretstorage': {
>       type: 'boolean',
>       description: localize('argv.useInMemorySecretStorage', "Ensures that an in-memory store will be used for secret storage instead of using the OS's credential store. This is often used when running VS Code extension tests or when you're experiencing difficulties with the credential store.")
>     }
>   }
> };
> if (isLinux) {
>   schema.properties!['force-renderer-accessibility'] = {
>     type: 'boolean',
>     description: localize('argv.force-renderer-accessibility', 'Forces the renderer to be accessible. ONLY change this if you are using a screen reader on Linux. On other platforms the renderer will automatically be accessible. This flag is automatically set if you have editor.accessibilitySupport: on.'),
>   };
>   schema.properties!['password-store'] = {
>     type: 'string',
>     description: localize('argv.passwordStore', "Configures the backend used to store secrets on Linux. This argument is ignored on Windows & macOS.")
>   };
> }
> ```

For reference, documentation on VS Code's commandline arguments can be found by running `code --help`, or in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line.

Comment: Thanks starball. That helped. Lets hope that someone enhances the implemented subset.

Answer (score 0):

The file doesn't seem to be explicitly documented anywhere, so I would say only change it as specifically directed, like by the docs or release notes. Most of the settings seem to be fixes/workarounds for bugs or other problems.

These settings are present in my file<sup>*</sup>:

- `disable-hardware-acceleration` (commented out)

  Release notes: [October 2019 (version 1.40)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_disable-gpu-acceleration)

  Docs: [Raspberry Pi](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/raspberry-pi)
- `disable-color-correct-rendering`

  Release notes: [February 2020 (version 1.43)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43#_electron-70-update)
- `enable-crash-reporter`

  Release notes: [August 2020 (version 1.49)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49#_disabling-crash-reporter)
- `crash-reporter-id`

  I couldn't find anything on this on the official site, but it comes with a description in the file itself:

  ```js
  // Unique id used for correlating crash reports sent from this instance.
  // Do not edit this value.
  ```
- `locale`

  Docs: [Display Language](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales)

I also found these from searching `argv.json` in the docs:

- `enable-proposed-api` in [Using Proposed API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api)
- `password-store` in [Settings Sync](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync)

---

* I'm using VSCodium 1.82.2, if that's relevant