# vscode remote development: What information is copied to the local machine?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm evaluating if using [vscode remote development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) to connect and develop against an EC2 instance.  We will be executing Jupyter Notebooks (or just plain python scripts) against S3/RDS data.

We would like to prevent the data from being stored persistently on the developer's local file system.  This includes generated assets, logs, etc.

Does `vscode Remote` copy anything over to the local machine file-system?

- I understand that regardless, the information will be in my local machine's memory (which is acceptable so long as no persistent data trail is left behind).
- I also understand that the developer would be able to exfiltrate this data if they wanted to act maliciously.  The goal is NOT to prevent that (as it's almost impossible), but we just want to provide development environments that are easy to clean up.
- While we could accomplish this using `Glue`, it is overkill, expensive, and the developer experience suffers greatly.  I assume the same is true of Sagemaker.

Comment: [remote jupyter notebooks are a thing](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks). why do you need to use a whole remote development extension? I don't know the exact answer to your question, but the answer in some way is going to be definitely yes. especially with respect to workspace caching of things. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77876923/11107541. I also can't wrap my head around how you could be okay with someone having data in RAM and assume the user is malicious, but be okay with it because it's "not persisted" (how the heck will you control that?).

Comment: @starball sorry I think you misunderstood the goal (I'm assuming the user is NOT malicious due to the other controls we have in place).  I'm trying to create more of a "clean room" development environment with first class DX (code complete, co-pilot, ability to run other tools, etc).   When the project is done, I want to be able to just nuke the ec2 instance, s3 & RDS and be confident that all data got cleaned out.  

I can trust our developers NOT to abuse certain features that would breach the "clean room".

Comment: I'll do some testing on `--user-data-dir` to see what ends up over there. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: user data dir is also where user-level configuration goes. so if you use it for sandboxing, there'll have to be copying over of those files from the default user data dir, unless you intentionally don't want that.